# Python Groupby Running Total/Cumsum column based on string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I want to create 2 Running Total columns that ONLY aggregate the `Amount` values based on whether `TYPE` is `ANNUAL` or `MONTHLY` within each `Deal`
so it would be `DF.groupby(['Deal','Booking Month'])` then somehow apply a sum function when `TYPE==ANNUAL` for the first column and `TYPE==MONTHLY` for the second column.

This if what my grouped DF looks like + the two Desired Columns.

```
Deal  TYPE   Month   Amount     Running Total(ANNUAL)   Running Total(Monthly)
A    ANNUAL   April    1000       1000                    0
A    ANNUAL   April    2000       3000                    0
A    MONTHLY  June     1500       3000                   1500
B    MONTHLY  April    11150      0                      11150
B    ANNUAL   July     700        700                    11150
B    ANNUAL   August   303.63     1003.63                11150
C    ANNUAL   April    25624.59   25624.59                0
D    ANNUAL   June     5000       5000                    0
D    ANNUAL   July     5000       10000                   0
D    ANNUAL   August   5000       15000                   0
E    ANNUAL   April    10         10                      0
E    MONTHLY  May      1000       10                      1000
E    ANNUAL   May      500        510                     1000
E    MONTHLY  June     500.00     510                     1500
E    ANNUAL   June     600        1110                    1500
E    MONTHLY  July     300        1110                    1800
E    MONTHLY  July     8200       1110                    10000
```

Comment: whoops my mistake, fixed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: but what if i wanted to create two columns? wouldnt df.groupby(['Deal', 'TYPE']).Amount.expanding().sum().unstack(level=1) only work for one column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filters` and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
mask = df.TYPE.eq('ANNUAL')
cols = ['Running Total(ANNUAL)','Running Total(MONTHLY)']
df.loc[mask,'Running Total(ANNUAL)'] = df.loc[mask,'Amount']
df.loc[~mask,'Running Total(MONTHLY)'] = df.loc[~mask,'Amount']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0)

df[cols] = df.groupby(['Deal'])['Running Total(ANNUAL)','Running Total(MONTHLY)'].transform('cumsum')

print(df)
   Deal     TYPE   Month    Amount  Running Total(ANNUAL)  \
0     A   ANNUAL   April   1000.00                1000.00   
1     A   ANNUAL   April   2000.00                3000.00   
2     A  MONTHLY    June   1500.00                3000.00   
3     B  MONTHLY   April  11150.00                   0.00   
4     B   ANNUAL    July    700.00                 700.00   
5     B   ANNUAL  August    303.63                1003.63   
6     C   ANNUAL   April  25624.59               25624.59   
7     D   ANNUAL    June   5000.00                5000.00   
8     D   ANNUAL    July   5000.00               10000.00   
9     D   ANNUAL  August   5000.00               15000.00   
10    E   ANNUAL   April     10.00                  10.00   
11    E  MONTHLY     May   1000.00                  10.00   
12    E   ANNUAL     May    500.00                 510.00   
13    E  MONTHLY    June    500.00                 510.00   
14    E   ANNUAL    June    600.00                1110.00   
15    E  MONTHLY    July    300.00                1110.00   
16    E  MONTHLY    July   8200.00                1110.00   

    Running Total(MONTHLY)  
0                      0.0  
1                      0.0  
2                   1500.0  
3                  11150.0  
4                  11150.0  
5                  11150.0  
6                      0.0  
7                      0.0  
8                      0.0  
9                      0.0  
10                     0.0  
11                  1000.0  
12                  1000.0  
13                  1500.0  
14                  1500.0  
15                  1800.0  
16                 10000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `.expanding.sum()` which will maintain a multiIndex of the groups that you can unstack to get separate columns for each type. Use another `groupby` to fill the missing values within each group accordingly. Concatenate it back.

The nice thing about this is that it can be done for arbitrarily many types, without needing to define them anywhere explicitly.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = (df.groupby(['Deal', 'TYPE'])
         .Amount.expanding().sum()
         .unstack(level=1)
         .groupby(level=0)
         .ffill().fillna(0)
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .drop(columns='Deal'))

pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

#### Output

```
   Deal     TYPE   Month    Amount    ANNUAL  MONTHLY
0     A   ANNUAL   April   1000.00   1000.00      0.0
1     A   ANNUAL   April   2000.00   3000.00      0.0
2     A  MONTHLY    June   1500.00   3000.00   1500.0
3     B  MONTHLY   April  11150.00      0.00  11150.0
4     B   ANNUAL    July    700.00    700.00  11150.0
5     B   ANNUAL  August    303.63   1003.63  11150.0
6     C   ANNUAL   April  25624.59  25624.59      0.0
7     D   ANNUAL    June   5000.00   5000.00      0.0
8     D   ANNUAL    July   5000.00  10000.00      0.0
9     D   ANNUAL  August   5000.00  15000.00      0.0
10    E   ANNUAL   April     10.00     10.00      0.0
11    E  MONTHLY     May   1000.00     10.00   1000.0
12    E   ANNUAL     May    500.00    510.00   1000.0
13    E  MONTHLY    June    500.00    510.00   1500.0
14    E   ANNUAL    June    600.00   1110.00   1500.0
15    E  MONTHLY    July    300.00   1110.00   1800.0
16    E  MONTHLY    July   8200.00   1110.00  10000.0
```